# Check how many characters are in a variable XSL

Tags: xslt

Hi there basically I need to find how many characters are in a variable using XSL

```
if characters($Title == 12) {  
    execute code;
}
```

Basically something like above obviously this is incorrect can any one help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively you can do the equivalent to and if/else statement in XSL:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length($Title) = 12">
    <!-- code when the check is true -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- code when it's false -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I have seemed to notice that this does not count spaces ' ' .. is there a way to go about having these counted as well?

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0:

```
string-length($title) = 12
```

Take notice that diacritical marks also would be counted.

In XPath 2.0 you cuold use:

```
string-length(normalize-unicode($title)) = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

> basically I need to find how many
>   characters are in a variable using XSL
>
> ```
> if characters($Title == 12) { execute code; }
> ```

**Use**:

```
 <xsl:if test="string-length($Title) = 12">
   <!-- Your code here -->
 </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

`string-length($varname)` will tell you the length of a variable containing data that can be interpreted as a string.